# How to boolean compare histogram_quantile against gauge?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to compare the returned instant vector of `histogram_quantile` against a gauge.

```
(
  histogram_quantile(1.0,
    sum by (le) (
      rate(discoverer__round_duration_seconds_bucket[1m])
    )
  )
)
>= bool
(
  discoverer__info_interval_seconds * 0.0001
)
```

But what I get back is `no datapoints found`. Please notice that I multiple the gauge with a very small number. This is just to make clear that it will be always <= than the quantile. Both "subqueries" work if I enter them separately into Prometheus Web UI.

**Why is this not working?**

When I switch out the quantile with a rate it suddenly works:

```
(
  rate(discoverer__round_duration_seconds_sum[1m])
  /
  rate(discoverer__round_duration_seconds_count[1m])
)
> bool
(
  discoverer__info_interval_seconds * 0.02
)
```

[image]

I made sure that all queries work by themselves.

What I would like to see is something similar to the second screenshot.
Just with a percentile, because I prefer it's calculation for my alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by wrapping the gauge in `avg()`. Still, I would really like to know why it works in one example without `avg()`.

```
histogram_quantile(1.0, sum by (le) (rate(discoverer__round_duration_seconds_bucket[1m]))) > bool avg(discoverer__info_interval_seconds) * 0.1
```